# How to make continuous vertical line on crystal reports?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, report

Hello I want to replicate the following on crystal reports:

[image: Report Sample]

Right now I have it as follows on CR (Yellow being the report header and then the page headers, blue the details section, green the report footer which I need it to print at the bottom of the page, and the read part being the thing that I want to accomplish)

[image: Explanation]

Any suggestions on how can I accomplish to create a section that draw at least all those vertical lines from the end of the details section all the way to the start of the report footer section?

UPDATE

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can draw a vertical line from blue section to top of the green section. So that you can get vertical line as u see in 1st image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on your line and under Format Line, check the "Extend to Bottom of Section when Printing" box. That should print the line all the way to the Footer. You may also have to check the "Print at Bottom of Page" box in the Section Expert under Report Footer.

EDIT:

After some trial and error we finally found the solution:
In Preview mode, click on one of the lines in the detail section. Now drag the bottom of the line all the way down to the Report Footer. You should see the line extending as you drag the end of it down. Make sure that you extend it all the way until you are on top of the horizontal line in the Report Footer. Once you let go, the line should stay. If it doesn't you didn't drag it far enough. Try that and let me know. This only works in Preview Mode!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however that did not solve the problem, I added a page footer and added that line with that option checked and it still did not go all the way to bottom.

I figured that this option allows you to extend a line in a particular section to make it as long as the section itself, however the blank space that I want to fill is the rest of the page that did not get any records on it, and that's exactly what I want fill with the vertical lines

Comment: So what exactly is the red section? Is it part of the detail section? Do you have any sections suppressed? Can you post a screenshot of your report design?

Comment: I'm sorry to be a pain, but can you also post a screenshot of the report in Preview so we can see where the lines end? That would be very helpful!

Comment: dont worry bro, I should have uploaded it on the first place xD

Comment: See revised answer please.

Comment: sorry, did not work, page footer appears under the report footer...
do i have to go to the section expert and check one of the options?
I am unable to move the page footer over the report footer

Comment: Very strange. Have you tried extending the lines from the Detail Section into the Report Footer? I'm doing the same layout here on my machine and the lines display perfectly. If you are willing you can send me the report and I'll look at it.

Comment: fine, I've never sent a file(s) from here, do I need to send them to your email?

Comment: One more thing before I give you my email, try and shorten the lines in the detail section so they don't extend all the way to the top and bottom. I just had one line in my report that didn't display at all and it was stretching over the top into the header section. If that doesn't work I'll post my email address.

Comment: sorry, same result =(

Comment: OK, I think I've got it. In Preview mode, click on one of the lines in the detail section. Now drag the bottom of the line all the way down to the Report Footer. You should see the line extending as you drag the end of it down. Make sure that you extend it all the way until you are on top of the horizontal line in the Report Footer. Once you let go, the line should stay. If it doesn't you didn't drag it far enough. Try that and let me know. This only works in Preview Mode!

Answer (score 0):

Move the lines down to reach the report-footer section then right click on the section experts and set print at the button of the page to true.